# Increment value by one if value is NULL

Tags: mysql

The query below works if there's at least one row in the table. I want it to return 1 in the event it returns `NULL`.

```
mysql> desc users_map_item;
+----------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| map_user_id    | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| map_item_id    | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| unique_item_id | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| item_owner     | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| privilege      | tinyint(1)            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

SELECT case when unique_item_id IS NULL then isnull(max(unique_item_id)+1) else     
max(unique_item_id)+1 end as unique_item_id FROM users_map_item WHERE map_user_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value is `NULL`, then adding 1 just creates a `NULL` value.

Also, the `case` statement should be using the `max()` aggregation function for the condition.

```
SELECT (case when max(unique_item_id) IS NULL then 1
             else max(unique_item_id)+1
        end) as unique_item_id
FROM users_map_item
WHERE map_user_id = 1;
```

This can be simplified to:

```
select coalesce(max(unique_item_id)+1, 1)
FROM users_map_item
WHERE map_user_id = 1;
```

EDIT:
The following is really about the perversity of hidden columns (a MySQL extension) in this particular case. Your original query is a little mind-bending when there are no rows.  The following query would return one row with the value of `NULL`:

```
select max(unique_item_id)
from users_map_item
where map_user = 1;
```

However, this query returns *no* rows, which is not the same thing as a row with a `NULL` value:

```
select unique_item_id
from users_map_item
where map_user = 1;
```

This expression mixes the two:

```
SELECT (case when unique_item_id IS NULL then 1
             else max(unique_item_id)+1
        end) as unique_item_id
FROM users_map_item
WHERE map_user_id = 1;
```

Does it return one row or zero rows?  The answer is "1" because it is an aggregation query.  But what is the value of `unique_item_id` for that row?  Well, there is no such value.  I would argue that "none" is different from `NULL`, but MySQL treats it as `NULL`, which is why the query works.  This wouldn't work in most other databases.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MAX(COALESCE(unique_item_id, 0)) + 1 FROM users_map_item WHERE ...
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `isnull(max(unique_item_id)+1)` just type `1`.